# Importing into 2D array gives an option base 1 not 0

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

I am importing a range into a 2D variant. However it is a variant starting at 1. to 100 ect.

but what if i want to import from variant of 0 to 99?

I.E.

```
Sub test()

    Dim curr_navTable() As Variant
    update_range = [updated_range].Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Range.Value` returns a 1 based 2D array.  That's what it does, you can't change that.   If you want to convert it to a 0 based array you'll need to copy the data to a new array